# Binding XAML to codebehind in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, code-behind

I have this textblock:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Coordinates" Text="Some Coordinates"/>
```

How can I access this object from the codebehind? I'm trying to replace the hardcoded coordinates in Locaton(), with the content of "Text":

```
private void DestinationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Location loc= new Location (20.2127297,-87.4625591);
    myMap.Center = loc;
    myMap.ZoomLevel = 8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without looking it up, at a guess I'd say something like:

```
this.Coordinates.Text = loc.ToString();
```

This will, of course, depend on what ToString() returns - you may have to override it to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Based on your comment I think you want something like this.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Coordinates" Text="20.2127297,-87.4625591"/>
```

```
private void DestinationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
   string[] doubles = this.Coordinates.Text.Split(',');
   var xCoord = double.Parse(doubles[0], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   var yCoord = double.Parse(doubles[1], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

   Location loc= new Location (xCoord,yCoord); 
   myMap.Center = loc; 
   myMap.ZoomLevel = 8; 
}
```

First split the TextBlock-1`string` into separate substrings. Then parse them do `double`.

Comment: I need to use the info on "Text" on the button click event. I don't need to bind from codebehind to XAML, but to XAML to the codebehind

Comment: @Batuu don't forget you need to specify the datacontext to get the binding to work.

Comment: @Mark-AR: Maybe I got you wrong. What do you want to do? A TextBox for user input or just a TextBlock to present some data?

Comment: @Batuu I want to display several coordinates on textblocks, and when the user clicks on DestinationButton, I need it to use the content of Text for the Location(Text here) method...